# how to make a release using the github api

Tags: python, github

I tried to do it by examples, but at startup it outputs a 404 error

```
import requests
payload ={"tag_name":"v1.0.0","target_commitish":"master","name":"v1.0.0","body":"Description of the release","draft":"false","prerelease":"false","generate_release_notes":"false"}
url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/user/test/releases'
headers = {'Authorization': 'token token'}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers,data=payload)
print(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
import requests
payload ={"tag_name":"v1.0.0","target_commitish":"master","name":"v1.0.0","body":"Description of the release","draft":"false","prerelease":"false","generate_release_notes":"false"}
url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/user/test/releases'
headers = {'Authorization': 'token token', 'Accept': 'application/vnd.github+json'}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)
print(response)
```

Comment: <Response [404]>